# Spring: Multipart-Formdata in a single object

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

Is it possible to bundle the contents of a multipart form into a single object in the corresponding controller method?

I.e. how do I transform the method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mult", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<SomeBean> upload(@RequestBody MultipartFile multipartFile, @RequestParam String param)
```

into a method with the following signature:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mult", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<SomeBean> upload(@RequestBody MultipartWrapper wrapper)
```

where `MultipartWrapper` contains the multipartFile and the additional param:

```
public class MultipartWrapper {
    private String param;
    private MultipartFile multipartFile;

    // Getters & Setters
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a @ModelAttribute as in other controllers:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mult", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<SomeBean> upload(@ModelAttribute("cmd") MultipartWrapper wrapper) {
    ...
}

@ModelAttribute("cmd")
public MultipartWrapper getWrapper() {
  return new MultipartWrapper();
}

public class MultipartWrapper {
  private String param;
  private MultipartFile multipartFile;

  // Getters & Setters
}
```