# Can't construct instance of MultipartFile

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I get the following error when trying to save a vehicle entity attached with an image:

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information

Here is my controller code and the request body class I made:

```
@PostMapping("/save")
    public ResponseEntity<Vehiculo> postVehiculo(@RequestBody VehiculoSaveBody json) throws IOException{
        Vehiculo vehiculo = json.getVehiculo();
        Version_Vehiculo version = json.getVersion();
        MultipartFile file = json.getFile();
        System.out.printf(file.getResource().getFilename());
        return vehiculoService.postVehiculo(vehiculo, version, file);
    }

@Data
public class VehiculoSaveBody{
    Vehiculo vehiculo;
    Version_Vehiculo version;
    MultipartFile file;
}
```

I've seen in every tutorial that everyone receives de file as a RequestParam and specifies the name, something like @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file.

Is the error caused by the way I receive the Json as a RequestBody?

Comment: maybe this is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19405628/spring-multipart-formdata-in-a-single-object

Answer (score 0):

try `@MultipartForm` of org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.providers.multipart.MultipartForm instead of `@RequestBody`